# How to to select two columns (Name, Value) and return as single result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a table that has a column for `Name`, and a column for `Value` and an `ID`.  There can be multiple rows for the same `ID`. I would like to create a select that will return a single row for each ID and the values in the `Name` column would be the column name, and the `Value` would be the value.  Example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Attribute
(
    AttributeID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,

    Value varchar(20) NOT NULL
   ) ;
```

Data:

```
{1,"Color", "Blue"},{1,"Material", "leather"}
```

Would like Select to return:

```
[AttributeID:1, Color:Blue, Material: leather]
```

I have been playing with `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` but not getting what I need.

Comment: You may wish to do some research on the advantages and disadvantages of an EAV database model.

Comment: Yes Nick! I found this to be excellent: http://www.sturnus.co.uk/performance/2008-07/the-curse-of-the-name-value-pair/

Comment: Especially the disadvantages (like ability to query). This is a horrible way to store data.

Comment: You need dynamic pivot but do you really want a 1 Km table?

Comment: We have NO idea of what names and values we will be getting for this case.  This is the current architecture.  Can you please elaborate on the dynamic pivot, as I have not been able to get this to work.

Comment: I understand the query limitations, I am actually working on moving this data to an elastic search solution, and working on process to query the relational data and move it to non relational for the search service.

Comment: Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query It gathers all the names in a query so you dont have to write them manually.

Comment: @Mihai, add this link as an answer, I will mark it as the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Eh its just a link.Work out an answer to your question and post it here,I`ll upvote it.

Comment: HAHA, your link was exactly what I needed.  I was working with something similar, but could not get it to work.  You link was perfect...so thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70267/discussion-between-csharpatl-and-mihai).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mihai's link.  I was able to do what I

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Name) 
            FROM VariantAttribute c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT variantid, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select variantid
                    , Name
                    , value
                from VariantAttribute
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max([Value])
                for Name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Before I get more slack about how I am storing this data.  There is not a way out of it at the moment, but this query is to push this data to Azure Search (uses Elastic search) to be able to easily search on this data.